# Extract Type T from Seq[T]

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have a case class which has got two fields which are a `Seq[Objects]`. These two objects belong to two different case classes.

```
  case class Passport(country: String, name: String)
  case class DrivingLicence(code: String, name: String)
  case class Docs(passports : Seq[Passport], driv: Seq[DrivingLicence])

  val pass1 = Passport("UK", "Michael")
  val pass2 = Passport("USA", "Michael")

  val driv1 = DrivingLicence("A2", "Mich")
  val driv2 = DrivingLicence("A4", "Mich")

  val docs = Docs(Seq(pass1,pass2), Seq(driv1,driv2))
```

I can generate a map with all the attributes and their types like follows:

```
  val r = currentMirror.reflect(docs)
  val mapType = r.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
    .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r.reflectField(s)}
    .map(r => r.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r.symbol.typeSignature)
    .toMap
println("Map of Types: "+mapType)
```

And the output is:

> Map of Types: Map(driv -> Seq[DrivingLicence], passports ->
>   Seq[Passport])

But what I would like is to get rid of the Seq part, and obtain the inner type. Something like:

> Map of Types: Map(driv -> DrivingLicence, passports -> Passport)

How could I access the inner type of a `Seq[_]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a list of type arguments with `typeArgs`, but it will return `List[Type]`, so you would need to take the first element with `head`:

```
r.symbol.typeSignature.typeArgs.head
```

Comment: That was the thing!! Thanks a lot